# jQuery UI Autocomplete: Scrolling through the suggestions menu with tab

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I would like to scroll through the jQuery UI autocomplete suggestions when the user presses the tab key (and is simultaneously in the search field).

I believe that the answer to my question is closely related to the answer to the question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689405/making-jquery-uis-autocomplete-widget-actually-autocomplete).

```
$("#search").keypress(function (eventObject) {
   if (eventObject.keyCode==13){
      *what do I write here*
   };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your requirement then I don't think that exact scenario is supported with jQuery UI autocomplete.  You can *open* the autocomplete drop down when you press tab and then use the arrow keys to move through the list of items.

```
// Setup
$("#search").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: myItems
});

// Call on tab press
$("#search").autocomplete("search", "");
```

Comment: Nick, wouldn't there be a way to trigger the "down arrow key event" when the "tab key event" is caused, conditionally based on whether the user had focus in your (#search) element? Figuring out the correct event to trigger would solve my problem if I could link the two events together.