# Is there a way to make jquery ui autocomplete fill in the remaining word in the input without selecting from the drop down?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making jQuery UI's Autocomplete widget *actually* autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689405/making-jquery-uis-autocomplete-widget-actually-autocomplete)

The default functionality seems to be that once you have typed a few letters, you still need to select the option from the drop down (either with arrow keys or with the mouse).

Is it possible to cause the autocomplete to fill in the remaining characters of the input with say the top most option?

Of course, it should still allow you to type over those characters if you wish. I expect the standard functionality would be that if you pressed tab or enter, it would complete the input with the option selected, if you continued typing it would overwrite the suggestion, and if you pressed delete it would delete the currently suggested characters.

EDIT: My apologies, this is what I was looking for: [Making jQuery UI's Autocomplete widget *actually* autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689405/making-jquery-uis-autocomplete-widget-actually-autocomplete/3690097#3690097)

Comment: how about using another input right behind it and make the front input transparent. But this requires pixel precision, and it also can be a different colour perhaps grey :)

Comment: btw google uses this sort of technique :)

Comment: @cammil: You can feel free to answer your own question, I think it would be valuable :)